# Secure Java we application using Azure AD SAML but do not want to use Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I have created a Java application but I need to secure it using Azure AD SAML using Spring Boot I have done it but when I am trying to convert it for without Spring Boot it is not working.

Here is my SamlAppConfig file where I do configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SamlSecurityConfiguration extends SamlServiceProviderServerBeanConfiguration {

@Override
protected SamlServerConfiguration getDefaultHostSamlServerConfiguration() {
    final SamlServerConfiguration samlAppConfig = new SamlServerConfiguration();
    final LocalServiceProviderConfiguration serviceProvider = getLocalServiceProviderConfiguration();
    samlAppConfig.setServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
    return samlAppConfig;
}


private LocalServiceProviderConfiguration getLocalServiceProviderConfiguration() {
    final LocalServiceProviderConfiguration serviceProvider = new LocalServiceProviderConfiguration();

    serviceProvider.setSignRequests(false);
    serviceProvider.setWantAssertionsSigned(false);
    serviceProvider.setEntityId("https://localhost:8443");
    serviceProvider.setSignMetadata(false);
    serviceProvider.setKeys(rotatingKeys());
    serviceProvider.setBasePath("/");
    List<Object> namedIds = new ArrayList<>();
    namedIds.add("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent");
    namedIds.add("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress");
    namedIds.add("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified");
    serviceProvider.setNameIds(namedIds);
    List<ExternalIdentityProviderConfiguration> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    providers.add(externalProvider());
    serviceProvider.setProviders(providers);
    return serviceProvider;
}

private ExternalIdentityProviderConfiguration externalProvider() {
    final ExternalIdentityProviderConfiguration externalIdentityProviderConfiguration = new ExternalIdentityProviderConfiguration();
    externalIdentityProviderConfiguration.setMetadata("https://dev-673817.okta.com/app/exkqkkg0kUVEvNyg14x6/sso/saml/metadata");
    try{
        externalIdentityProviderConfiguration.setAuthenticationRequestBinding(new java.net.URI("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"));
    }catch(URISyntaxException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    externalIdentityProviderConfiguration.setSkipSslValidation(true);

    return externalIdentityProviderConfiguration;
}

private RotatingKeys rotatingKeys() {
    X509Certificate myCertificate = CertUtil.getCertificateByName("spring", "keystore.jks", "secret");
    final RotatingKeys rotatingKeys = new RotatingKeys();
    SimpleKey activeKey = new SimpleKey();
    activeKey.setName("spring");
    try {
        activeKey.setCertificate(getCertificateForKey(myCertificate));
    } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    rotatingKeys.setActive(activeKey);
    return rotatingKeys;
}

private String getCertificateForKey(X509Certificate myCertificate) throws CertificateEncodingException {
    return getEncoder().encodeToString(myCertificate.getEncoded());
}
}
```

And this is my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(GET, "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(GET, "/api/samlLink").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/home")
        ;

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
    }
}
```

And to read creti:

```
public class CertUtil {

    public static X509Certificate getCertificateByName(String certificateAlias, String trustStoreName, String password) {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            loadKeyStore(keyStore, trustStoreName, password);
            Certificate cert = keyStore.getCertificate(certificateAlias);
            if (cert.getType().equals("X.509")) {
                return (X509Certificate) cert;
            }
            throw new Error("Could not find a suitable x509 certificate for alias " + certificateAlias + " in " + trustStoreName);
        } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e) {
            throw new Error("Error opening keystore: " + e.getCause(), e);
        }
    }

    private static void loadKeyStore(KeyStore keyStore, String jksPath, String jksPassword) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            CertificateException {
        char[] password = null;
        if (jksPassword != null) {
            password = jksPassword.toCharArray();
        }
        keyStore.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(jksPath), password);
    }
}
```

This is my filter class where I check for the authentication:

```
public class SamlAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        
        Authentication authentication = (Authentication) req.getUserPrincipal();
        SamlAuthentication samlAuthentication = (SamlAuthentication) authentication;
        if (samlAuthentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        } else {
            
        }
         
    }

}
```

But I am create jar and include it in my java application but it's not working and I am using this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M31</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I correct the security so I can secure my application using Java filter and not Spring Boot?